# Redundant ToString code?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I was wondering :

writing this code :

```
 DataRow[] g = new DataRow[1] ;
 var t=new StringBuilder().AppendFormat("{0}", g[0]["aaa"].ToString());
```

Resharper shows it like :  ( notice the gray )

[image]

[image]

<kbd>3 questions please</kbd>

1) removing `ToString`() , how will the object will output its display string without calling the removed `ToString`() ?

2) does it suggest to remove it because he *already* calls it internally ? or because of another reason ?

3) not removing ToString() , will it call it twice ?

Comment: @Curt My questions are totaly different from the duplicate ! I didn't ask why it compiles !

Comment: What are the results when you remove the ToString() call?  I already know the answer, but you asking the first question, seems sort of pointless.

Comment: @Ramhound its the same result. I dont understand your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is redundant because `AppendFormat` (like `String.Format`) internally already converts it to a string and `String.ToString` is always redundant.

Actually it uses the [`ICustomFormatter.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icustomformatter.format.aspx) method on every provided parameter.

It's also redundant in terms of useless. So even if no work needs to be done multiple times(`AppendFormat` will not try to convert a string to a string), it is pointless since `AppendFormat` *would do* it anyway. Hence resharper tries to simplify your code here.

Comment: Internally calls `ToString()` on non-null instances rather ;p

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, `ToString()` will not be called on string instances.

Comment: redundant  = wont be executed twice ? or at all ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I've only just edietd my answer to take this point into account. If it's executed twice depends on the provided formatter. Normally `Format` would just return the string that was specified(if it is already a string). However, resharper tries to simplify your code at least :)

Answer (score 4):

You may want to see: [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

**Processing Order**

> Each value in the parameter list that corresponds to a format item is
>   converted to a string by performing the steps in the following list.
>   If any condition in the first three steps is true, the string
>   representation of the value is returned in that step, and subsequent
>   steps are not executed.
>
> 1. If the value to be formatted is null, an empty string ("") is returned.
> 2. If the composite formatting method includes a parameter of type IFormatProvider that also implements the ICustomFormatter interface,
>      the value is passed to the ICustomFormatterFormat method.
> 3. If the value implements the IFormattable interface, its IFormattableToString method is called.
> 4. The type's ToString method, which is either overridden or inherited from the Object class, is called.

Whereas [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) seems to inherit from `System.Object` and doesn't implmenet `IFormatProvider` or `IFormattableToString`, so I believe, its `ToString` method is called to get the string representation internally, and having explicit `.ToString` is considered redundant.